# Why 3 points for asking a question

Tags: discussion, reputation

Has there been a change so that asking a question receives 3 points?

I'm showing +3 for a question I posted, and can't figure out the reason.

Comment: [not as far as I know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), you start with 1 rep and if you accept an answer you get `+2` for accepting it.

Comment: No there hasn't. You most likely got +5 and -2.

Comment: Perhaps if you linked to the question someone could give you a more definitive answer. (At least, before the meta hordes cast their votes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't receive points for asking a question.

You receive :

- 5 rep per question upvotes
- 10 rep per answer upvotes
- 15 rep per answer accepted

You probably have 3 because you lost 2 because of a downvote.

Comment: Except my profile summary appeared to show +3 and not +5 and -2 as normal hmm. Maybe I misperceived.

Comment: @Jaycee The reputation feed above shows +3 if you got an upvote (+5) and a downvote(-2).

Answer (score 6):

This is because there is a known edge case with the voting system.

The rules are:

- 5 points for a question upvote
- 10 points for an answer upvote
- -2 points for a downvote
- +2 points for accepting an answer
- 15 points for having an answer accepted
- -1 point for downvoting
- points are reversed if the action that gave them are undone.

and - what people tend to forget:

- points don't go below 1.

So if the first vote you get is a down-vote your reputation remains at 1, but then if that down-vote is reversed you get a "free" +2.

So that way your reputation can be at +3 even though you don't apparently have any votes on any of your posts. It must be pointed out that is is not "real" reputation. If the users' reputation score is recalculated at any point this "+2" will disappear.

Comment: That means, in a rare edge case, a user can get a lot of reputation for a bad answer that he revisited and all prevoius votes would be reversed without any upvote?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - nope. Just the +2. Any further down-votes will remove the rep gained.

Comment: If a new user has a question with a score of -10 (all downvotes) and he edits the question and the downvotes are reversed, would he get 10*2 reputation back that he never lost?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - Ah - possibly. However that is highly unlikely. Also it's not "real" so if the users' reputation is recalculated it will disappear.

Comment: Intresting. I don't think that there are any loop holes with that -> not worth fixing it.

Answer (score 5):

For every upvote on a question you get still 5 rep. But if you also receive a downvote that cost you 2 rep.

Answer (score 0):

It's +5 from up votes, and -2 from down votes.

The +2 might have come from you [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)